# how to refresh google spreadsheet (and specifically the now() function) every x seconds?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like google spreadsheet to automatically refreshes calculation. I have made simple timers with NOW() and I would like to see the timer going down

So far, I have tried the googleclock() function and is only updated every minute, which is not 
enough. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Write script and try Class ClockTriggerBuilder : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder?hl=en
and use this method for periodically creating trigger: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder?hl=en#after(Integer)